# How do you convert this SQL statement to LINQ to SQL, with a query in a select statement

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

The table has `staffid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `supervisorid`. The `supervisorid` is linked to the `staffid` on the same table.

```
select 
 StaffID,
 FirstName + ' ' + LastName as 'Name',
 Email,
 Supervisor = (Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName
                  From tblStaff staffinner 
            Where staffinner.StaffID = staffouter.SupervisorID)
from tblStaff staffouter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var staff = from s1 in tblStaff
            select new
            {
               StaffID = s1.StaffID,
               Name = s1.FirstName + " " + s1.LastName,
               Email = s1.Email,
               Supervisor = (from s2 in tblStaff
                            where s2.StaffID == s1.SupervisorID
                            select s2.FirstName + " " + s2.LastName).First()
            };
```

Comment: A couple minor tweaks: Make sure to add in the space between the first and last names for both select projections. Also, you need to take only the `First` result for your Supervisor otherwise you're changing the type of Supervisor from `string` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var staff = tblStaff
            .Select(a => new
                         {
                          StaffID = a.StaffID,
                          Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                          Email = a.Email,
                          Supervisor = tblStaff
                                       .Where(b => b.StaffID = a.SupervisorID)
                                       .Select(b => b.FirstName + " " + b.LastName)
                                       .First()
                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a subselect, or would a self join suffice here?

```
var staff = from person in tblStaff
            join supervisor in tblStaff on person.StaffID equals supervisor.SupervisorID
            select new 
            {
                person.StaffID,
                Name = person.FirstName + ' ' + person.LastName,
                person.Email,
                Supervisor = supervisor.FirstName + ' ' + supervisor.LastName
            };
```

If you need to do an outer join, use DefaultIfEmpty().

Comment: I tried doing the self join, but visual studio did not like that.

Comment: The following works against the EF Version of Northwind containing the ReportsTo field: `from emp in Employees
join supervisor in Employees on emp.EmployeeID equals supervisor.ReportsTo
select new 
{
    emp.LastName,
 emp.FirstName,
 SuperLast = supervisor.LastName,
 SuperFirst = supervisor.FirstName
}` You may want to double check the syntax you used for the self join as both EF and LINQ to SQL support it.